# Products are not showing When i search through REST client plugin

Tags: magento-1.9, php, rest-api

This is the XML content I got when I search in the browser/REST client Firefox plugin...

```
<magento_api>
    <data_item/>
    <data_item/>
    <data_item/>
    <data_item/>
    <data_item/>
    <data_item/>
</magento_api>
```

I have 6 items in the Magento store... But the `product_id`, `description`, `sku` and etc are not showing...

Please help me

Comment: I searched like this ...127.0.0.1/api/rest/products

Comment: Are you searching as a guest API user? Does the user have the proper ACLs?

Comment: Each and every tokens have been generated and all the REST roles, permission have been given already ..please tell me which setting I should have to do ...Thanks in advance

Comment: S sir ..I have given all the permissions to GUEST also ...

Comment: Did you check for conflicting extensions et cetera? Or is this a clean installation?

Answer (score 1):

http://localhost/magento/api/rest/search/products?search_term=-------&limit=10&page=1

Here the ----- lines denotes, which text you want to search.

Use the above one, it will give the result from the core api.